# AngularJS multiple single bindings vs one large binding

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-ng-repeat

What would be more efficient/a better practise: binding multiple object properties to different scope properties or binding the whole object to the scope and accessing the properties in the template.

Here are some examples of both scenarios:

Single object binding:

```
directive('info', [function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            object: "="
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>\
            <div>{{ object.something }}</div>\
            <div>{{ object.something2 }}</div>\
            <div>{{ object.something3 }}</div>\
            <div>{{ object.something4 }}</div>\
            <div>{{ object.something5 }}</div>\
        </div>',
        replace: true
    };
}]);

<info ng-repeat="info in infoArray" object="info"></info>
```

Multiple bindings:

```
directive('info', [function(){
    return {
        scope: {
            something: "=",
            something2: "@",
            something3: "@",
            something4: "=",
            something5: "@",
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>\
            <div>{{ something }}</div>\
            <div>{{ something2 }}</div>\
            <div>{{ something3 }}</div>\
            <div>{{ something4 }}</div>\
            <div>{{ something5 }}</div>\
        </div>',
        replace: true
    };
}]);

<info 
    ng-repeat="info in infoArray" 
    something="info.something"
    something2="info.something2"
    something3="info.something3"
    something4="info.something4"
    something5="info.something5">
</info>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your directive needs to do.
I use directives mostly for custom inputs; usually I have a central object with the 'model' (an object that I potentially send to the server) that can be complex, and other attributes used to set UI options of the custom input.
For example: a simple datepicker could have a structure like this:

```
directive('datepick', [function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      model     : "=ngDatepicker",
      format    : "@format",
      readonly  : "@ngRead"
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    /* etc. ... */
```

and these could be like:

```
$scope.model = {
  day : '',
  month : '',
  year : '',
  wholedate : ''
};
$scope.format = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
$scope.read = false;
```

and the HTML could be like:

```
<datepick ng-datepicker="model" format="format" read="read"></datepick>
```

In the example you posted (I'm assuming it's only to display info, without manipulating it) I would go with the single object binding; that way if the objects inside infoArray change structure you don't need to change all the html templates.